# Unable to cast object of type 'Model.TreeModel' to type 'ViewModels.TreeViewModel'

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create objects from another object which has a list of objects. But I am getting a casting error on the line where I do the casting. Is there a way to cast object of different collection on to another collection.

Code:

```
public List<TreeViewModel> getAllTreeNodesFromModel()
{
    treeNodeViewModel = treeModel.getTreeNodes().Select(a => new TreeViewModel
      {
        Children = a.Children.Select(c => new TreeViewModel{Value = c.Value}).ToList(),
        Value = a.Value,
       }).ToList();

      return treeNodeViewModel;
  }

// Making list observable
public ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> TreeView
{
    get
    {
        return treeView; 
    }

    set
    {
        if (treeView == value) return;
        treeView = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TreeView");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeView}">
   <TreeView.Resources>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
           <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Here is my model:

```
public class TreeModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TreeModel> Children { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public TreeModel()
    {
        Children = new List<TreeModel>();
    }

    public TreeModel(string name, List<TreeModel> children)
    {

        this.Name = name;
        this.Children = children;
    }

    public List<TreeModel> BuildTree(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        return (
          from s in strings
          let split = s.Split('.')
          group s by s.Split('.')[0] into g  // Group by first component (before /)
          select new TreeModel
          {
              Value = g.Key,
              Children = BuildTree(            // Recursively build children
                from s in g
                where s.Length > g.Key.Length + 1
                select s.Substring(g.Key.Length + 1)) // Select remaining components
          }
          ).ToList();
    }

    // View Model
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public  List<TreeViewModel> Children { get; set; }

    // List VM mapped from Model
    public List<TreeViewModel> getAllTreeNodesFromModel()
    {
         treeNodeViewModel = treeModel.getTreeNodes().Select(a => new TreeViewModel
         {
             Children = a.Children.Cast<TreeViewModel>().ToList(),
             Value = a.Value,

         }).ToList();

         return treeNodeViewModel;
     }
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeView}"  >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowModel}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Propably in line with error you should create TreeViewModel, not cast:

    Children = a.Children.Select(c => new TreeViewModel{Value = c.Value}).ToList()

Comment: Please show the signature of TreeModel and TreeViewModel (how classes are defined) and TreeViewModel's constructor.

Comment: @Baboon I edit the original post

Comment: @JakubJarzabek I plug in your suggestion it seems to be working but I am having problem in the view .... I updated my post for your comment

Comment: What's the signature and constructor of TreeViewModel?

Comment: @Baboon   public TreeViewModel()
        {

            treeNodeViewModel = new List<TreeViewModel>();
            treeModel = new TreeModel();
        }

Comment: This is beginning to devolve into "debug my code for me".

Answer (score 1):

Copying answer from comment:
You should create TreeViewModel for each model's child, not cast:

```
Children = a.Children.Select(c => new TreeViewModel{Value = c.Value}).ToList()
```

As `Children` are recursive it would better to write it that way:

```
 public List<TreeViewModel> getAllTreeNodesFromModel()
 {
    treeNodeViewModel = treeModel.getTreeNodes().Select(a => getChildTreeNodesFromModel(a)).ToList();

    return treeNodeViewModel;
  }

 public List<TreeViewModel> getChildTreeNodesFromModel(TreeModel a_model)
 {
      return new TreeViewModel
      {
           Value = a_model.Value,
           Children = a_model.Children.Select(c => getChildTreeNodesFromModel(c)).ToList()
      }
 }
```

Comment: I found out what the problem is on the view I was pointing to the wrong viewmodel. I changed to this: 
Thank you Jakub for your help on the viewmodel side!!

Comment: <TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeView}" >
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" Content="{Binding Value}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.Resources>
        

            </TreeView>